# Is there a way to set different special bonds for different atom groups in the same structure in LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, lammps

I am running some simulations on a metal organic framework and I need to set different 1-4 `coul` and `lj` parameters for different components on my MOF. I need to set it to be `0 1` for the inorganic part and `0.833 0.5` for the organic part.

The line I want in LAMMPS is `special bonds` but I'm not sure how to avoid applying to to all the atoms. There is the "group" function, but I don't think this is what I want as it doesn't allow me to specify 1-4 interactions. Would `molecule` be helpful?

Any advice appreciated! Unfortunately, it's not possible for me to use another software.

Comment: The question is not exactly clear to me (probably since this is not my field of study). However, if you are looking to model a specific set of atoms, which have different bonds from the others, you can simply try setting that atom as a different type. For example, you can identify one set of `C` as type 1 whereas the other is type 2. Then you can define different interactions to each.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.